# MS Access VBA code editor character encoding and copy/paste

Tags: vba, ms-access

What is the actual encoding used in Access' VBA editor? I have been searching for a concrete answer for quite a while but with no luck.

I thought it was UTF-8 but I'm not very certain.

My main issue is that when writing a query in VBA I sometimes need to test it in Access' query editor. When copy-pasting however, I lose my native characters (greek in my case) as they turn to gibberish.

I have tried pasting in a text editor and saving it as different encodings but I can never recover the original characters.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Let me explain this a bit further:

As you can see I can write my greek characters in the VBA editor normally:

[image: sample in vba editor]

However, copying the first line in Access' query editor, I get the following:

[image: paste in query editor]

Same goes for a simple text editor:

[image: text editor]

So I am inclined to think that the problem lies inside the clipboard, due to the encoding used for the greek characters. I guess they are not Unicode, as I indeed have to make the change in the System Locale for non-unicode characters. So how are these characters saved/copied? In what encoding?

**Answer**

Actually this problem was solved by switching the keyboard input language to greek (EL), when copying the actual test string.

I am still not sure however, as to why that happens. If anyone can provide some insight into this, I would love to hear it.

Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

The VBA editor does not support Unicode characters, either for input or display. Instead, it uses the older Windows technology called "code pages" to provide support for non-ASCII characters.

So, the character encoding in the VBA editor corresponds to the code page that is used by the Windows system locale as specified in the "Regional and Language Options" control panel. For example, with my system locale set to "Greek (Greece)"

[image: cpGreek.png]

I can enter Greek characters into my VBA code

[image: vbaGreek.png]

However, if I switch my Windows system locale back to "English (United States)"

[image: cpUS.png]

and re-open my VBA project, the Greek characters have changed to the corresponding characters in the new code page

[image: vbaUS.png]

Comment: Thanks but this is not the problem I am facing. I have already made this change to the system locale. Please see my edited question above.

Answer (score 5):

If "Control Panel" -> "Regional and Language Options" -> "System Locale" is set correctly but you still suffer from this problem some times then note that **while you're copying** your keyboard layout must be switched to the non-English language.

This is applicable to all non-unicode-aware applications not only VBA.

**Credit** goes to @parakmiakos

Comment: In my experience, in order for the text to be pasted in the correct code page, setting the keyboard to the non-English language is only required while **pasting**, even if the keyboard was in English while copying

Comment: @DanZ are you sure? In my case the opposite is true. I've tested both copy-pasting from a non-unicode-aware application(VBA) to unicode-aware one (notepad++) and the opposite direction

Comment: Oops, you're right of course. I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote my comment. What's required is setting the keyboard to the non-English language while **copying**. The state it's in when pasting doesn't matter. BTW, would you mind editing your answer to specify this detail?

Answer (score 0):

details in this:  http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/use-greek-characters-visual-basic-editor-t2097705.html

Looks like making sure your OS is set properly, and font choice inside the VBA editor.

Comment: I think this goes beyond the font selection. I am using Courier New (Greek) if this is of use to you. See my edited question above. Thanks

Comment: This thread has some insights into Unicode issues with the clipboard: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?514847-Clipboard-and-Greek-text

Comment: Alan... you hit it on the head for me... the solution for my encoding problem was the clipboard. Solution was copying from Excel -> Notepad ++  -> VBA and it worked.

Comment: Amit, what if I want to do that programmatically. I'm sure there's a way!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Cyrillic characters. Part of the problem is solved when set the System locale correctly.

However, The VBA editor still does not recognize cyrillic characters when it has to interpret them from inside itself.

For example it can not display characters from the command:

```
Msgbox "Здравей"
```

but if the sheet name is in cyrillic characters it does it well:

```
Msgbox Activesheet.Name
```

Finally, it turned out that these kind of problems were solved when I changed to 32 bits version of MS Office.