# ms access "enter parameter value" when I enable macros

Tags: windows, ms-access

I have an issue in MS Access.

I have a report that calls a query where the results are filtered with a value taken from the form that calls the report.

The condition on the field looks like this:  ​[FORMS]![Main Menu]![Combo42]

When I open the  project with the **macros DISABLED** the report works okay.

But  **when I enable macros**  (either from the enable content pop-up  yellow line that appears on top or  enabling all  macros in the trust setting ) and I try to open the report the **"enter parameter value" pop up appears.**

It looks like when the I enable macros "Combo42" field becomes unaccessible from the query.

I have tried all the possible combinations from "trust center" settings menu even though only the "enable macros" seems to have any affect.

Is has to be setting related because the issue appears only on "freshly installed" office that I installed by my self (i tried many versions) but when I use pre-configured office (i.e. company laptop) the issue doesn't appear.

Does anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

UPDATE!

after some time investigation tying to answer some questions i found the solution here

[MS Access VBA code editor character encoding and copy/paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560121/ms-access-vba-code-editor-character-encoding-and-copy-paste)

different outcome same root cause.

Comment: Form References are brittle I suggest just working around the problem by creating a public property.  Set the property in the combo42 after update event.  (I suggest going full property with set, get public functions and a private state)  see here for more information on access public functions: https://sfmagazine.com/post-entry/march-2018-access-user-defined-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming the reference to a valid field name after enabling Macros? This can help:

[Enter Parameter Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/enter-parameter-value-when-run-query)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response. 
I did try to rename it but nothing changed.

Comment: The link you send talks about more generic "code-wise" issues except the 

"or a field may not be available within that scope."

Something like that seems to be the issue. When I enable the macros "Main menu" seems to be out of scope of the query.